# How to load id list from config for player Inventory? [Bukkit]

Tags: bukkit

I have this code:

```
public boolean hasItem(Player player){
    int empty = 0;
    int armors = 0;

    for (String str : config.denyBlocks) {
         for (ItemStack item : player.getInventory().getContents()) {
            if (item == null || item.getType() == Material.getMaterial(str)) empty++;
          }
     }


    for (ItemStack armor : player.getInventory().getArmorContents()) {
            if (armor == null || armor.getType() == Material.AIR) armors++;
    }

    return empty == player.getInventory().getContents().length && armors == player.getInventory().getArmorContents().length;
}
```

but for some reason it does not work. The tests did not work, if not the first cycle, the test runs.

This code works:

```
public boolean hasItem(Player player){
    int empty = 0;
    int armors = 0;

         for (ItemStack item : player.getInventory().getContents()) {
            if (item == null || item.getType() == Material.getMaterial(4)) empty++;
          }



    for (ItemStack armor : player.getInventory().getArmorContents()) {
            if (armor == null || armor.getType() == Material.AIR) armors++;
    }

    return empty == player.getInventory().getContents().length && armors == player.getInventory().getArmorContents().length;
}
```

Where 4 - id block Minecraft. Please help!!

Comment: whats the failure/issue you are running into

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are using String for getting Material by ID, but the Bukkit expects Material name. Instead of that you should convert it to Integer. Use `Integer.parseInt(string)`.

```
for (String str : config.denyBlocks) {
     for (ItemStack item : player.getInventory().getContents()) {
        if (item == null || item.getType() == Material.getMaterial(Integer.parseInt(str))) empty++;
     }
}
```